# decoding h264 video frames using decodeByteArray always return null

Tags: android, h.264

I want to convert the h264 frame byte-data to Bitmap array so that I can feed it to other sources, I tried this:

```
@Override
public ARCONTROLLER_ERROR_ENUM onFrameReceived(ARDeviceController 
deviceController, 
ARFrame frame) {
byte[] data = frame.getByteData();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
 if(bitmap != null){
   // do something
 }
return ARCONTROLLER_ERROR_ENUM.ARCONTROLLER_OK;
}
```

But it doesn’t work, the decodeByteArray can’t decode the byte data returned by the frame and it is always return null. 
any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

`BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()` simply isn't going to be capable of this. It's an unsupported format.

Because of complexities like P-frames, B-frames and I-frames, it takes a class with a little more state to be able to decode an arbitrary H.264 frame:

[`MediaCodec`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678717/how-to-play-raw-h264-produced-by-mediacodec-encoder) is a pretty decent code sample. There are many more out there.